# Leaving a user-made function in Gdb gracefully after accidentally stepping into it

Tags: debugging, gdb

Say that main() calls foo() which calls bar(). Obviously foo() and bar() are functions defined by the user/programmer. Also, say that these functions are called in the middle of the caller's function.

If I am in Foo() and I suddenly step into bar() accidentally, how do I leave bar() and continue Foo()'s immediate instruction after the call is made in Gdb?

I tried to use the "finish" command, but I've seen it finish foo()'s function call and return me back to main.

Also I used the "ni" command only when program counter points to the "call bar()" instruction inside foo(), but that didn't work since it's not a library function. I assume "ni" is used to skip library functions.

For now, the only idea I have is to create a breakpoint to the instruction after the "call bar()", but I feel like there's a better way to do this. Is there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Finish` works fine for me. Even GDB manual says "Continue running until just after function in the selected stack frame returns." about the `Finish` command

Comment: Finish should work, but there may be issues, if you are debugging optimized code or lacking debug information.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to use the "finish" command, but I've seen it finish foo()'s
>   function call and return me back to main.

This is true if you are in `foo()`'s gdb frame (frame 1) when calling `finish`. Try to switch to `bar()`'s frame (frame 0) and call `finish`. gdb should finish only one frame (frame 0) in this case.